# Passar valores da gridView para a activity de edição

Tags: java, android

Por favor, quem poder me ajudar fico muito grato

Estou com problema para passar o valor do radioGroupOpcoes para tela de edição.

```
 // Abre a tela de cadastro/edição com os registros para edição.
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
      textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
      String text = textView.getText().toString();
      Intent AbreTCadastro = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TCadastro.class);
      AbreTCadastro.putExtra("notas", Integer.parseInt(text));
      startActivity(AbreTCadastro);
            finish();
        }
    });
    Activity de cadastro/edição que recebe os dados.

    editTextHoras = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.IdHoras);
    editTextDestino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IdAutoCompletDestino);
    editTextDia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IdAutoCompletDia);
    editTextLinha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IdAutoCompletLinha);

    radioGroupOpcoes = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.IdCumpriuHora);
    radioCumpriuHoraSim = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.IdRadioSim);
    radioCumpriuHoraNao = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.IdRadioNao);
    radioConfirmar = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.IdRadioConfirmar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    tcadastro = intent.getIntExtra("notas", 0);
    MdConsulta salva = new MdConsulta(this);
    MdCampos notas = new MdCampos();
    notas = salva.getNotasById(tcadastro);
    editTextHoras.setText(notas.horas);
    editTextDestino.setText(notas.destino);
    editTextDia.setText(notas.dia);
    editTextLinha.setText(notas.linha);
    if (radioCumpriuHoraSim.isChecked()) radioCumpriuHoraSim.setChecked(true);
    if (radioCumpriuHoraNao.isChecked()) radioCumpriuHoraNao.setChecked(true);
    if (radioConfirmar.isChecked()) radioConfirmar.setChecked(true);

Só os editTextHoras, editTextDestino, editTextDia e editTextLinha retornam para a edição, Os RadioButtons não retorna.
```

Segue a outra parte do código

```
public class InsereDados extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public InsereDados(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView TxtId;
        TextView TxtDestino;
        TextView TxtDia;
        TextView TxtHora;
        TextView TxtLinha;
        TextView TxtCumpriuhora;
        TextView TxtCheio_vazio;
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View   viewLista    =    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.inseredados, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder  =   new ViewHolder();
        holder.TxtId    =   (TextView)  viewLista.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
        holder.TxtDestino    =   (TextView)  viewLista.findViewById(R.id.txtDestino);
        holder.TxtDia   =   (TextView)  viewLista.findViewById(R.id.txtDia);
        holder.TxtHora   =   (TextView)  viewLista.findViewById(R.id.txtHora);
        holder.TxtLinha   =   (TextView)  viewLista.findViewById(R.id.txtLinha);
        holder.TxtCumpriuhora   =   (TextView)  viewLista.findViewById(R.id.txtCumpriuhora);
        holder.TxtCheio_vazio   =   (TextView)  viewLista.findViewById(R.id.txtSituacao);
        viewLista.setTag(holder);
        return viewLista;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
holder.TxtId.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MdCampos.KEY_ID))); holder.TxtDestino.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDdestino.KEY_DESTINO))); holder.TxtDia.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MdCampos.KEY_dia))); holder.TxtHora.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MdCampos.KEY_horas))); holder.TxtLinha.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDlinhas.KEY_LINHA)));
holder.TxtCumpriuhora.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MdCampos.KEY_cumpriuhora)));  holder.TxtCheio_vazio.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MdCampos.KEY_cheio_vazio)));    
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde você salva os valores booleanos  do radiogroup?

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo e desculpe o atraso no retorno de sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu reverti a edição porque não percebi como ela melhorava em algum aspecto o conteúdo da mesma, fora o fato de o título ter sido mudado para algo sem relação alguma com a pergunta. Se a edição revertida era importante, desculpe-me e peço que a refaça da maneira correta, sem prejudicar o título e formatando corretamente o código. Veja como [utilizar corretamente o editor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).